# Query for a ticket system involving cases and casts on many attributes

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

I have this `SELECT` statement that inserts into a temp table and it is **slow**!  Right now it takes ~1500 ms to run and only deals with ~7000 rows.  As the data grows larger the longer it will take.

I am using SQL server 2014.

Is there anyway to improve performance of all these `case` and `casts` in the statement?

```
select  a.TicketID as [Ticket ID],
    b.TicketTypeText as [Type],
    b.TicketTypeID as [*TypeID],
    isnull(a.TicketDescriptionReport, a.TicketDescriptionUser) + isnull(' [' + h.AcuDocTypeText + ' ' + g.DocUserFirst + ' ' + g.DocUserLast + ']','') as [Description],
    k.Names as [Assigned To],
    i.name as [Requested By],
    CAST(DateRequested as Date) as [Date Requested],
    case when InScope = 1 then 'Yes' when InScope = 0 then 'No' else '???' end as [Scpe],
    c.ticketStatusText as [Status],
    d.SignatureUserName  as [Pending User Sign],
    case when a.ticketstatusid = 4 then CAST(a.LastModifiedDate as date) else null end as [*CompleteDate],
    cast(case when @p_Clock = d.SignatureUserClock
                or (b.TicketTypeID = 3 and (exists(select assign.AssignClock from #assignments assign where assign.TicketID = a.TicketID and assign.AssignClock = @p_Clock))) then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*PendingCurrentUser],
    CAST(case when @p_Clock = a.UserRequested then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*RequestedCurrentUser],
    CAST(case when a.TicketStatusID = 4 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*TicketCompleted],
    CAST(case when a.TicketStatusID = 10 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*TicketRefused],
    CAST(case when @isIT = 1 or @p_Clock = d.SignatureUserClock or @p_Clock = a.UserRequested  then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*ShowMe],
    CAST(case when a.TicketStatusID < 4 and @isIT = 1 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*AllowRejectEdit],
    @isIT as [*isIT],
    d.SignatureID as [*SigID],
    CAST(case when a.TicketTypeID in (0,3) and @isIT = 1 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*CanConvertITRF],
    CAST(case when a.TicketTypeID IN (0,2,3) and @isIT = 1 and a.TicketStatusID < 4 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*CanEditSigs],
    a.TicketDescriptionReport as [*TDR],
    CAST(case when a.TicketTypeID IN (1,2) then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*CanPrint],
    case when a.TicketTypeID = 1 then 'AddChangeUser' when a.TicketTypeID = 2 then 'ITRF' else '' end [*RptName],
    case when a.TicketTypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end [*IsACU],
    case when a.TicketTypeID = 2 then 1 else 0 end [*IsITRF],
    isnull(j.NoteCount,0) as [*NoteCount],
    isnull(j.AllNotes,'') as [*AllNotes],
    CASE WHEN a.TicketTypeID <> 1 then a.TicketDescriptionUser else
+ N'ACU Type: ' + h.AcuDocTypeText + char(13)
+ N'User Clock: ' + cast((DocUser) as varchar(32)) + char(13)
+ N'User Last Name: ' + (DocUserLast) + char(13)
+ N'User First Name: ' + (DocUserFirst) + char(13)
+ case when BadgePinNumber is not null then N'Badge Pin: ' + cast((BadgePinNumber) as varchar(32)) + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SimilarToUser is not null then N'Similar User: ' + cast((SimilarToUser) as varchar(32)) + char(13) else '' end
+ N'Changes Effective: ' + cast((ChangesEffectiveDate) as varchar(32)) + char(13)
+ case when ActiveDirectory = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when InternetAccess = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when EmailAccess = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when ShareAccess is not null then N'(Read): ' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when ShareAccessWrite is not null then N'(Write): ' + case when ShareAccessWrite = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end + char(13) else '' end
+ case when PhoneExtension is not null then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when Voicemail = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when MsOffice = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when MsProject = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when MsVisio = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(AutoCAD, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when CAccess = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SoftwareUG = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SoftwareSolidWorks = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when RequirePC = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when RequireLaptop = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(RequireMonitorCount, 0) > 0 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when RemoteAccess = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when RequirePrinter = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(RequireBadgeScanner, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(RequireI, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when RequireOther is not null then N'Requires Other Equipment: ' + RequireOther + char(13) else '' end
+ case when ChangeClock is not null then N'Change Clock to: ' + cast(ChangeClock as varchar(32)) + char(13) else '' end
+ case when ChangeDept is not null then N'Change Department to: ' + ChangeDept + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AddRm = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when ChangeB = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(timeOverride, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(Receipt, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when CpMove = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(DSProf, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(EQProf, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when EtchP = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when FixB = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(GoalEditor, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(WaxD, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when PieceM = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(TSBo, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(ScrapM, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when Shipping = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(WIAl, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when isnull(WhatIf, 0) = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when Allo = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloH = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloCharges = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloReleaseCharges = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloBalanceInv = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloShipment = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloAdj = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloHTabs = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloCustSpec = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloViewMH = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloReportsInv = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloChargeWeights = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloOrder = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloBalance = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloSpecial = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloCharges = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloCast = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloReportsUsage = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloConsumeCharges = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloRev = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloChargeMaint = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AlloCloseH = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when TimecardApprovalDept is not null then N'Timecard Approval for Department: ' + TimecardApprovalDept + char(13) else '' end
+ case when eReqCreate = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when eReqApprove = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OtherRights is not null then N'Other Rights: ' + OtherRights + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbView = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbPoChange = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbPoApprove = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbShip = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbManualInvoice = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbCreditDebitMemo = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbCustomerReturns = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbCustomersEngines = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbViewCrCdSales = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbBillingFinance = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when OsbInvoice = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytAccountsPayable = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytAccountsReceivable = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytCycleCount = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytDock = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytGL = 1 then N'[Syteline] GL: Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytGlPost = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytInventory = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytItem = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytJobRoute = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytMiscIssueReceipt = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytPurchasing = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytViewOnly = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytReports = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytSalesMaintenance = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytSalesOrders = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytVendors = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytVouchersAuthorization = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytEnterOutOfDateRange = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when SytPostOutOfCurrentPeriod = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AccountingShareAccess = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
+ case when AccountingShareAccessWrite = 1 then N'Yes' + char(13) else '' end
    end as [*TDU],
    CAST(case when (@isIT = 1 or @p_Clock = d.SignatureUserClock) and 

a.TicketStatusID < 4 and a.TicketTypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as [*AllowEdit]
into    #output
from    db.dbo.Main a join
        db.dbo.TicketType b on a.TicketTypeID = b.TicketTypeID join
        db.dbo.TicketStatus c on a.TicketStatusID = c.TicketStatusID join
        db.dbo.employee i on i.clock = a.UserRequested left join
        PendingSig d on d.TicketID = a.TicketID left join
        db.dbo.OrderReport f on f.TicketTypeID = a.TicketTypeID and d.SignatureOrder = f.SignatureOrder left join
        db.dbo.AcuDetail g on g.TicketID = a.TicketID left join
        db.dbo.AcuDocType h on h.AcuDocTypeID = g.AcuDocTypeID left join
        TicketNotes j on j.TicketID = a.TicketID left join
        #assignmentList k on k.TicketID = a.TicketID
order   by a.TicketID, d.SignatureOrder
```

On a side note, the statement below take less than 100ms to run as a test to make sure it was all the `case` and `cast` that were causing this performance.

```
select  a.TicketID as [Ticket ID]
into    #output
from    db.dbo.Main a join
        db.dbo.TicketType b on a.TicketTypeID = b.TicketTypeID join
        db.dbo.TicketStatus c on a.TicketStatusID = c.TicketStatusID join
        db.dbo.employee i on i.clock = a.UserRequested left join
        PendingSig d on d.TicketID = a.TicketID left join
        db.dbo.OrderReport f on f.TicketTypeID = a.TicketTypeID and d.SignatureOrder = f.SignatureOrder left join
        db.dbo.AcuDetail g on g.TicketID = a.TicketID left join
        db.dbo.AcuDocType h on h.AcuDocTypeID = g.AcuDocTypeID left join
    TicketNotes j on j.TicketID = a.TicketID left join
    #assignmentList k on k.TicketID = a.TicketID
order   by a.TicketID, d.SignatureOrder
```

Sorry guys, I got derailed off this project for a little while, I'll update with more code and tables schema soon when I get the time, for now I'll give you this screenshot I had from yesterday. I'm not completely sure how to read execution plans but it shows the `Table Insert` taking 92% and the every other steps are 0-1%. The execution plan was lengthy to fit on one page, so I took a snippet of it. I'll post more of the stored procedure and and tables when I get the time to make it look nice and make sense.

[image: ToolTipMessage]

Here is what the execution plan shows if I comment all the Case and Casts out of the `SELECT`, as shown in the second block of code in this thread, and it will execute in ~100 ms.

[image: ToolTipNoCaseAndCasts]

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: If you've got some kind of schema showing all the DB tables and their structures, that would be **really** useful.

Comment: Like @Zak said  A schema will be helpful - You are allowed to insert an image into your post  or link to an external resource e.g github where the image is  saved

Comment: Your 2nd statement has probably a totally different plan, as the optimizer might remove some joins. Add all the columns you need in #1 and check runtime again. All those `CASE` and `CAST` should only add a bit more CPU, but not increase runtime 15 times.

Comment: This query strikes me as the tip of an iceberg — an indication that there are a lot of unconventional designs in this application. Tell us everything that might be relevant: the schema, the purpose of this query, what the various ticket type codes mean, what you will do with the result, …